# Filter Service Accounts / Non-User accounts from Search Results in SharePoint ONLINE

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, user-accounts

I am developing SharePoint **ONLINE** "Employee Directory" where I am able to get all the users information along with Service Accounts. The requirement is not the display the service accounts or non-user accounts(e.g, accounting@domainname.com, marketing@domainname.com etc) in the search results web-part.

There is one new Custom Attribute at AZURE Active Directory with the name "**employeeID**" which distinguish whether the user account is a service account or normal user account. How to map that Azure AD attribute to SharePoint ONLINE user property?

I have followed this link ( [https://thomasdaly.net/2016/01/16/hiding-people-from-people-search/](http://thomasdaly.net/2016/01/16/hiding-people-from-people-search/) ) but the newly created managed property is not appearing in the Property Filter dropdown of the Search Result's Change query.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to reuse the SPS-hidefromaddresslist attribute to filter out those accounts
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/beyondsharepoint/2016/11/11/restrict-disabled-users-in-search-results/

Comment: Thanks for your response Larsen. 
Is there anyway to sync that Azure AD Custom Attribute ("employeeID") to map to SharePoint ONLINE user property?

Comment: Only standard properties are mapped and hence indexed. Custom properties need to be synchronized manually for example using a script to iterate all User Profiles and fetch data from AAD or EXO. Also be aware that you need to add data into the fields before they are crawled and hence get managed/crawled properties to use for filtering in search

Answer (score 0):

There is "ShowInAddressList" Azure AD User object property that is editable and synchronized to “SPS-HideFromAddressLists” SharePoint User Profile property.

When I set 'ShowInAddressList' Azure AD User object property to false - the account does not appear in Microsoft 365 Search.

“Show in Global Address List” under m365 Admin Center and “Hide from global address list (GAL)” under Exchange Admin Center respect “ShowInAddressList” Azure AD User object property change (but not vise versa).

[more on this...](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/hide-non-personal-account-from-microsoft-365-search/)